# Array not updating after push inside mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, express, mongoose

I have a problem when I want to update an array by doing the push function. So now the array just showing and empty array. But when i do try catch and hit some endpoint , it just works perfectly, is there something that i miss ?

So here's my code

```
let localCompared = []
duplicate[0].map((v,i)=>{
        UserDummy.find({no_hp:v.no_hp},function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
          }
          if (data[0]) {
            localCompared.push(data[0])
          }
        })
      })
```

And this is the full code

```
app.post("/api/users/csv", async (req, res) => {
  csvData = req.files.csvfile.data.toString("utf8");
  return csvtojson()
    .fromString(csvData)
    .then(async (json) => {

      let newData = [];
      let user = [];
      let inserted = [];
      let duplicate = [];
      let localCompared = [];

      json.map((v, i) => {
        const inqueue =
          v.inQueue === "FALSE" || !v.inQueue || v.inQueue === ""
            ? false
            : true;
        const question =
          v.questioned === "FALSE" || v.inQueue === "" || !v.inQueue
            ? false
            : true;
        const id = v.id.replace("l:", "");
        const newno_hp = v.no_hp
          .replace(/p:+62/g, "0")
          .replace(/p:/g, "")
          .replace("+62", "0");

        newData.push({
          id: id,
          nama: v.nama,
          durasi: v.durasi,
          email: v.email,
          created: v.created,
          no_hp: newno_hp,
          brand_name: v.brand_name,
          inQueue: inqueue,
          questioned: question,
          source_form: "CSV Files",
          isWant: "",
          lastContacted: "",
          keterangan: '',
          journey_step: '0',
          journey_status: 'basic_journey',
        });
      });

    try {
        const userData = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/users/dummies')
        user.push(userData.data)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }

      const filteredDuplicate = newData.filter((elem)=>{
        return user[0].some((ele)=>{
          return ele.no_hp == elem.no_hp
        })
      })
      duplicate.push(filteredDuplicate)
      
      let filteredForInsert = new Set(user[0].map(({ no_hp })=> no_hp))
      let dataforInsert = newData.filter(({no_hp})=> !filteredForInsert.has(no_hp));
      inserted.push(dataforInsert)

      duplicate[0].map((v,i)=>{
        UserDummy.find({no_hp:v.no_hp},function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
          }
          if (data[0]) {
            localCompared.push(data[0])
          }
        })
      })

      if (inserted[0].length > 0) {
        inserted[0].map((v,i)=>{

          const newUser = new UserDummy(v)
  
          newUser.save(newUser)
          .then((results)=>{
            if (i+1 === inserted[0].length) {
              res.json({
                done_added:`${inserted[0].length} berhasil ditambahkan!`,
                duplicate:`${duplicate[0].length} terdeteksi duplikat!`,
                data:duplicate[0],
                localSameData:localCompared,
              })
            }
          }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
          })
        })
      }else{
        res.json({
          done_added:`Tidak ada data yang ditambahkan!`,
          duplicate:`${duplicate[0].length} terdeteksi duplikat!`,
          data:duplicate[0],
          localSameData:localCompared,
        })
      }
    });
});
```

I need the array to be updating and can be use in response , cause right now its just an empty array.

Comment: What is `data[0]`?

Comment: data[0] is a response from find() function from mongoose